# problem : python threads still alive after completion

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, isalive

As an exercise, I try to implement a non blocking mechanism to manage my own pool of threads (I know concurrent.futures). I ended with a problem: threads are always alive, even after they have completed.

I have written this little code to expose the problem.

```
import threading
import time

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, num):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.num = num + 1
 
    def run(self):
        print(f">>> {self.name} is starting")
        time.sleep(self.num*2.0)
        print(f"<<< {self.name} is finishing")

num_threads = 3
threads = []
for i in range(num_threads):
    t = myThread(i)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

num_finished_threads = 0
while num_finished_threads < num_threads:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    for t in threads:
        if t.is_alive:
            print(f"{t.name} is alive")
        else:
            t.join()
            num_finished_threads += 1
```

Can anyone explain me the behaviour of python: why those threads are still alive after completion ?

```
>>> Thread-1 is starting
>>> Thread-2 is starting
>>> Thread-3 is starting
Thread-1 is alive
Thread-2 is alive
Thread-3 is alive
Thread-1 is alive
Thread-2 is alive
Thread-3 is alive
Thread-1 is alive
Thread-2 is alive
Thread-3 is alive
<<< Thread-1 is finishing
Thread-1 is alive
Thread-2 is alive
Thread-3 is alive
Thread-1 is alive
Thread-2 is alive
Thread-3 is alive
Thread-1 is alive
Thread-2 is alive
Thread-3 is alive
Thread-1 is alive
Thread-2 is alive
Thread-3 is alive
<<< Thread-2 is finishing
Thread-1 is alive
Thread-2 is alive
Thread-3 is alive
Thread-1 is alive
Thread-2 is alive
Thread-3 is alive
Thread-1 is alive
Thread-2 is alive
Thread-3 is alive
Thread-1 is alive
Thread-2 is alive
Thread-3 is alive
<<< Thread-3 is finishing
Thread-1 is alive
Thread-2 is alive
Thread-3 is alive
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the `is_alive()` *function* instead of testing the `is_alive` attribute.

```py
    if t.is_alive():
        print(f"{t.name} is alive")
```

The reason why you didn't get an "...object has no attribute..." error when you tested `t.is_alive` is because a `Thread` instance *has* an attribute with that name. But the value of that attribute is the function, and a function is always "[truthy](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/)."

In order to find out whether or not the thread is alive, you have to *call* the function.

---

https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.is_alive

Answer (score 0):

You're thread will remain alive unless you `join` it.
Create a separate for loop to join all threads.
This will wait for the execution to complete, and will close the threads

```
while num_finished_threads < num_threads:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    for t in threads:
        if t.is_alive:
            print(f"{t.name} is alive")

    for t in threads:
        t.join()
        num_finished_threads += 1
print("done")



Thread-12 is starting>>> Thread-13 is starting

Thread-14 is starting
Thread-12 is alive
Thread-13 is alive
Thread-14 is alive
Thread-12 is finishing
Thread-13 is finishing
Thread-14 is finishing
done
```